# How can I print float in Pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, printing

I want to print something like this:

```
print("Average age is: " +  round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2)
```

Nevertheless I have a TypeError: `can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`

my float, means `round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2)` = 15.23

How can I print it ?

Comment: Change that `+` to a `,`. Might also be worth looking into `f-strings`

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that it doesn't know how to join (concatenate) a `float` and a `string`. In other words, it doesn't know the meaning of adding (`+`) a `string` and a `float`.

```
val=round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2)
print("float value: {}".format(val))
```

or

```
val=data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean()
print("float value: %.2f" % val)
```

should both work. I can test and provide more information if you're still stuck, but a sample `data` object would be useful.

Notes:

- The intermediate `val` is not needed, but I wanted to keep the `print` statements clean.
- The `%.2f` limits the floating point to 2 decimal places so the call to `round()` is not needed in the 2nd method.
- Both of the above methods above can support multiple insertions:

  - For example: `print("{} {}".format("hello","world"))` would print `hello world`.
  - The 2nd method would look like `print("%s %s" % ("hello", "world"))`.
- For the 2nd method, there are other choices aside from `%s` (string) and `%f` (float).

You might find https://pyformat.info/ helpful as it discusses both of these approaches in more detail.

The minimal amount of change you need is to wrap your `float` with the `str()` method to convert it from `float` to `string` (see code block below this paragraph). Once that's done, python knows how to concatenate two strings using the `+` operator. It'll work, but my opinion is that it clutters things up, especially if you are converting and concatenating multiple variables into one string variable or print statement.

```
print("Average age is: " +  str(round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your code you can make it work by adding `str()` before the value of your function because as the error points out, you can't concatenate (using the `+` operator) a string with a float.

```
print("Average age is: " +  str(round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2))
```

Answer (score 1):

A float can be printed by using {} brackets to specify where the value should go in your string and then using *.format* to replace those brackets (in order) by the values you want to have printed:

```
print("float value: {}".format(round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3.6, you can use `f` string as follows

```
print(f'Average age is: {round(data.loc[data["School1"]==1]["Age"].mean(),2)}')
```